# Angular inject service after loading

Tags: angularjs-scope

I have written a generic controller.

For context only, it's not part of the question: I extend the controller by way of setting call back functions during initialization, which the controller then calls upon specific events occurring. As such, when I wrote the controller (because it is generic), I don't know what services I might require.

So, how can I, after instantiating the controller in the view (using ngController), then inject a service. Obviously I will have a variable called myApp, and the result of myApp.controller(...).

Once injected, I then have a reference to scope when my callback functions get called. I could also add arguments to pass along something else if necessary. How  access the service?

Thank you

Sample code:

```
// Html:
ng-init="controller.init('myExtension')"


// then in the generic/abstract controller:
this.init=function(extensionName){
  window["extend_"+tag]($scope, this);
}

.... later on .....
     this.callBackFunction($scope)

// and finally (in a separate js file that is project specific):
function extend_myExtension(scope, controller){
      controller.callBackFunction=function(scope){
             // this is where I would like to use the service
      }
}


// this is where I would like to inject a service that
// I didn't know about when I wrote the generic/abstract controller
```

Comment: can you share your code? look like you want to call some async service to get data and load it and display in view once it is loaded. Is that correct?

Comment: OK, added some sample code above. As mentioned in another comment below, the generic controller is best thought of as an abstract class that I later extend Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Angular bootstraps, this is done in two phases:

1. The config phase: all services/controllers etc are registered, config blocks are called and the injector is initialized. You can only inject providers and constants in the config blocks because the services that will be returned by the providers are not
2. The run phase: all run blocks are executed and controllers/directives etc are executing (starting from ng-app). So there may be services injected as well.

What you want is impossible. The only thing you can do is to configure a provider in a config block. The configuration determines how the service will look like when it is injected in the run phase. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Could you elaborate on what problem you are actually want to solve? Having a generic controller that has no idea what to have injected sounds like a bad pattern. It isn't even 'unit testable'.

Comment: I added some sample code above. Basically, I want to write a controller that is a sort-of abstract class that implements basic functionality. I use it in several projects, so would like not to modify it if possible. Rather I would like to add to it by extending it at run time. Please see the sample code I posted in the original question.

Comment: It looks like you want to create a directive. A directive is a concept meant for reuse. It can have scope bindings which could function as parameters or to pass in data. A directive can have a controller and/or link function with business logic. I suggest you to learn about why and how Angular before you trying to solve your problem, because you may learn some Angular code patterns first. Please check out the documentation, tutorial and the concepts: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! I will try the directive and the provider.